# Performance testing in neoload

Tags: performance, testing, neoload

I am new to performance testing and I have a scenario in which there is an interviewer login in into the application and conducting an interview with the client.the candidate has to login at the same time and enter into the same interview session with the interviewer.can any1 please help me with how I can record the scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to record it in two separate sessions: first as the candidate and while you recording it you need to have another browser as the interviewer.
Once that's done then you start a new application with the candidate again but you would record the interviewer's action with the tool.
I think the hardest parts will be correlating sessions and founding rendezvouses points.
Let us know how you got on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with incognito and the normal window..I could run successfully.but another obstacle came my way when I reached the video part..it said some websocket issue.not sure what it is.will have to debug on it.plz help if any1 has knowledge on this.btw I'm using neoload

Thanks